# IR as 4th band in RGB composite (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, pansharpening, composite

In Symbology tab of a raster in ArcMap, in the section of Pan-sharpening, there is an extra option to check at the bottom: "4th-band Infrared Image" along with its weight:

[image]

I guess I have to add a 4th band while using "Composite Bands" tool, then give it a weight and so I will be able to see RGB mixed with IR view. 
What is the difference or **advantage** of using it over eg. CIR or 5-4-3 (Landsat 8)?

Answer (score 1):

This page explains the difference in equations when you apply a weight to the infrared layer according to which pansharpening method used:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-of-panchromatic-sharpening.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read this article. It explains how does each method apply NIR into its equation, but not when and why to use it. The sentense which is the most on the point is "By changing the near-infrared weight value, the green output can be made more or less vibrant." in Esri's method. But it still doesn't explain much. With my wild trials-errors I couldn't make an RGB composition with NIR look better or show more - that is why I'm looking for an actual case when it can/should be used.

Comment: I see. I believe if you use the weights correctly depending on the pansharp method and on the captors it should add quality to your image. I tried using weights for RGBI 0.15, 0.45, 0.35 and 0.05 respectively for a Landsat 8 scene using Esri method, and it gave me a pretty good result.